# Is *suppose* a noun here?

Tags: nouns

I faced the sentences:

> They are *suppose* to take a short term view and build product and keep customers satisfied.
>
> Well this wasn't *suppose* to be a screed, ...

(from http://www.postel.org/pipermail/end2end-interest/2008-April/007169.html)

Does *suppose* acts here as a noun?

What do this sentences with that *suppose* mean?

Comment: As Tim Pederick notes, the poster made a grammatical error. "Supposed to" means "are required to" or "really ought to". *The police are supposed to have probable cause before searching a person.  You're supposed to wash your hands after digging in the garden.*

Answer (score 2):

This is an error, but not an uncommon one. It should say "suppose**d** to".

In speech, the *d* of "supposed" (which gets de-voiced by many speakers, i.e. has a *t* sound) and the *t* of "to" are run together. Essentially, the *d* of "supposed" disappears.

As a result, in writing, it is a common mistake to also drop the *d* of "supposed". This might be because they're being casual (but probably not deliberately), careless, or because they simply think that's the right way to write it!

As for the meaning, "to be supposed to" means "to be intended/expected to". It is a verb, not a noun.

> They [companies] are suppose**d** to take a short term view...

"People expect companies to take a short-term view."

> Well this wasn't suppose**d** to be a screed...

"I did not intend this [email] to be a screed."